# Unable to log user in

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my code:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

@api_view(["POST"])
def user_login_api_view(request):
    username = request.data.get("username")
    password = request.data.get("password")

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    print(user, password, username)

    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

This is my request body for login:

```
{
    "username": "testuser111@test.test",
    "password": "testpassword111"
}
```

Here's the print result:

`None testpassword111 testuser111@test.test`

I register a user like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ..serializers import UserSerializer

class UserCreateApiView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.create_user(self.request.data)

    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

with this request body:

```
{
    "username": "testuser111@test.test",
    "password": "testpassword111"
}
```

User serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
```

List user code:

```
class UserListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all().values("id", "username")
    serializer_class = UserListSerializer

class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
```

List response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "last_login": null,
        "username": "testuser111"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "last_login": null,
        "username": "testuser1111@test.test"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "last_login": null,
        "username": "testuser111@test.test"
    }
]
```

And in response I get 401. How do I log a user in properly?

Comment: You are not  hashing password in your serializer

Comment: The default [`authenticate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users) method takes in an `username`. Yet you are passing an `email` as `username` on your payload, so its not able to find anything thus returning `None`.

Comment: username can contain @ and  . character therefor username can be looking like email, problem is that users he created have no usable password as it is not hashed properly

Comment: @iklinac since I'm not hashing it in either login or register it should still work. I know it's a terrible security flaw but it's a todo app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`get_queryset(...)`** method os supposed to return `QuerySet` object, not to create any objects.

```py
# views.py

class UserCreateApiView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

```py
# serializers.py

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

Comment: I tried that but still no luck. List and get details works fine. But still no luck with logging in

Comment: I edited the question with list response

Comment: @AlexIronside you should create new user, ones you already created have not usable password, or change their password using set_password

Comment: I did create a new user. The last one is new

Answer (score 1):

`CreateAPIView` will not call `get_queryset` ( not sure where you got that idea from)

You should properly write your `UserSerializer` so it hashes up the password

for example:

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['password'] = make_password(validated_data['password'])
        return super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Users you already registered have no usable password so you should update their password if you want to use them or recreate them